# How to remove duplicate lines in which there are no values or the value is NULL

Tags: sql, reduce

I am developing an SQL query using a pivot table join, and I've finally got a result, but there are duplicate entries when I join on the target table; there are no unique keys, so I use month and year as on condition.

```
Monthss PRE_DATA           CURR_DATA    TARGET_DATA
Apr-14  22870              22870        NULL
Apr-14  22870              22870        NULL
Apr-14  22870              22870        106509.8964
Mar-14  24515              24515        NULL
Mar-14  24515              24515        NULL
Mar-14  24515              24515        114306.3855
```

I want to remove duplicate entries and show the actual data but it give me hifi.

I'd like the result in this format:

```
Months  PRE_DATA        CURR_DATA       TARGET_DATA
Apr-14  22870           22870           106509.89
Mar-14  24515           24515           114306.3855
```

Comment: I've cleaned the formatting and the English up a touch, but I'm afraid I've no idea what you mean by `it give me hifi` - could you explain a little?

Comment: Can you give us your SQL that you have so far and the structure of the tables?

Comment: first i use pivot and then use CTE for getting actual result,up to this stage data come correctly when i use inner join with this cte at that time i get this kind of data,  the table which i use with inner join it doesn't have unique value that's why result show like this i dont understand which kind of join i used or how to remove data